# Multiple water tanks at different heights connected to same water line, which drains first?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am now in charge of water at the school I work at. The fire department wanted us to add an additional 60,000 gallons of water. We added (4) 15,000-gallon above-ground storage, all interconnected with an 8-inch line. It is roughly at the same height as two underground cisterns, a 30,0000 gallon, and a 20,0000 gallon that are also connected to each other by a 4-inch line. We then have (3) 15,0000-gallon tanks above both of those sets (roughly 10 feet or so) connected by a 3-inch line.  Each set is filled independently (and I don't really care about the filling rate).

My question is, if all 3 sets are full, and all three sets are connected to a 4-inch line that feeds the campus when I open up a water outlet, let's say a fire hydrant at the bottom of campus (50 feet below the elevation of the tanks), which tanks are going to start draining?

My thought is that the three tanks of the highest elevation will start draining first, and as those empty, the water line will more or less match the other tanks, and water is released from the system...maintaining the same height...as in the water level height. My friend thinks that even though the three highest-elevation tanks will most likely drain first, the other tanks will also be draining.

We are going to get some plastic cups and try to simulate the problem. Here is a picture more or less.
[image]

Comment: Is it all gravity fed or are there pumps in the system? If there are pumps, where are they located? They will only equalize in height if there is feedback in the system to limit the pressure.

Answer (score 3):

If you drain the water *slowly*, you'll maintain a constant water level across your entire water volume. This means, for example, that your higher-altitude tanks will drain into your lower-altitude tanks, unless they are sealed against the pressure or have some other kind of backflow preventer.

If you drain the water *rapidly*, such as via a fire hydrant, the order in which the pipes empty is going to depend on the turbulent flow within the pipes. The practical equation for this is apparently the [Hazen-Williams equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazen%E2%80%93Williams_equation),

$$
v= kC R^{0.63}S^{0.54}
$$

with $k$ a unit-conversion constant, $C$ a coefficient describing the roughness of the pipe material, $R$ the "hydraulic radius" of the pipe, which depends on both its size and shape, and $S$ the slope, or the change in altitude (or perhaps change in pressure) per length of pipe. You then find the volume flow by multiplying this velocity by the area of the pipe.

It is plausible that the narrow pipe from the high-altitude reservoir increases the pressure in the system, but that you get more mass flow out of the bigger pipe from the lower-altitude tanks.

If you are responsible for this system, there is really no alternative to just testing it. Get whatever permit you need, open the hydrant, and run it until you(r team) has measured real level drops in all of your reservoirs. Testing will also reveal differences between your model and your reality. I once had a closed, recirculating cooling-water system fail because a piece of garbage somehow got into the water line — we talked for years about the red plastic cap that nearly killed that experiment.

Answer (score -1):

The highest tanks empty first. In effect, there is one single "water line" you can draw as a horizontal line across the entire drawing which starts at the top of the highest tank, and goes down from there. None of the other tanks will start to drain until the absolute water height in the highest tank has dropped to the top of the other tanks.

To understand why, note that the pressure caused by water depends *only* on the height of the water. It doesn't matter if there's a tank or bends in the pipe or anything, all you need to know is the height of the water column to determine the pressure. The pressure at the bottom of the higher tank is greater than the pressure at the bottom of the lower tank - since pressure is force divided by area, this means that water from the taller tank is pushing to get into the shorter tank. If there is room, water will flow into the shorter tank until the water levels are equal. The only way that water doesn't flow from one tank to another is when the pressures are equal, and that can only be achieved with equal absolute water heights.

Comment: Ok. I think this all makes sense. And I understand fast vs. slow drain. I do have backflow preventers on all three sets (as in after their common connection and before it goes into my 4 inch line). Thus, I know the higher tanks won't over fill the lower tanks. I don't think this will impact draining or will it? The water level will start going down at the highest three tanks then they will all go down (more or less) at the same time. BUT YES, I WILL test it and I will have cameras in each one. THANK YOU BOTH!